# Query to bring back Records from left table if not in right table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine having a Stores table:

- ID
- StoreNumber
- BranchName

Imagine having another "SalesData" table:

- ID
- Month
- Year
- StoreNumber
- AmountAquired

Stores table is always populated. The SalesData is NOT. It is only populated as and when.

I am struggling to come up with the following query where it will bring me back results where for every store if there is no record for it for the given month and year AND where AmountAquired is null.

At the same time another added complexity (perhaps a separate query) is where to bring back all stores where there is no data in the sales data (with the join on StoreNumber) but if there is data then to only bring back the row for that store that has data and disregard the row which has no data for that store.

I have tried doing a left outer join and right outer join but no go.

```
SELECT s.* FROM Stores s
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesData sd ON
sd.StoreNumber = s.StoreNumber
WHERE sd.Year = 2014 AND sd.Month = 11 AND sd.AmountAquired IS NULL.
```

this brings back only the records where the year and month is 2014 and 11 (not surprising since that is what I put down in the where clause!)

I want it where it brings me back records where there is no data in the salesdata OR where the month and year match the parameters given to it (and not for any other month or any other year unless NULL is in the column values)

It should ALWAYS bring back data (pretty much from the stores table to show all the stores...and any data not found for it in the sales data table (or even if data is there for the given month and year along with for stores which have no data for them)

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you tried making the second and an or?

Comment: @AxGryndr - yes, I believe so. that seems to sound right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for this type of query.  The mistake you made is that when performing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, you need to move filters that are related to the right table into the join `on` section.

To get only store that are missing sales for Nov 2014:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM Stores s
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesData sd ON
sd.StoreNumber = s.StoreNumber
AND sd.Year = 2014 AND sd.Month = 11
WHERE sd.AmountAquired IS NULL --no sales are found
```

And to get all sales for Nov 2014, including stores that had no sales, you can do this:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM Stores s
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesData sd ON
sd.StoreNumber = s.StoreNumber
AND sd.Year = 2014 AND sd.Month = 11
```

Comment: what about bringing back records where there is no year or month assigned in addition to the ones where the month and year is assigned, and when I mean not assigned I mean where Year and Month IS NULL

Comment: I updated the answer to include this scenario, see the 2nd select statement

Comment: This works to what I want it I believe. Confirmed as answer but will probably come back later with a further query. Great job

Comment: if the year and month is null is SalesData, and you want those records returned too, you'll need to add them to the condition in the LEFT JOIN (Not the WHERE clause), 
i.e. (sd.Year IS NULL OR sd.Year = 2014) AND (sd.Month IS NULL OR sd.Month = 11). (Note the brackets) This will return matching records in SalesData where the year is NULL or 2014, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just switch to an OR for the 2nd case?

```
(sd.Year = 2014 AND sd.Month = 11) OR sd.AmountAquired IS NULL
```

In the 1st example you ask for *"no record for it for the given month and year AND where AmountAquired is null"* - but if there's no record, then AmountAquired will be NULL by necessity.

That query is simply:

```
SELECT
  s.*
FROM
  Stores s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesData sd ON sd.StoreNumber = s.StoreNumber
WHERE
  sd.StoreNumber IS NULL
```